# Screen flickering Isuue on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I hope everyone doing well in this difficult time. Actually, I am having a screen flickering issue on my laptop with newly installed ubuntu 18.04. My laptop model is Dell Inspiron 15 5000 with Nvidia graphics. The flickering is not so intense but it is happening continuously which is just boring to work. Initially, I had ubuntu installed on my laptop and thought this flickering may be the cause of the wrong installation of operating system. That is why I have made a fresh installation of ubuntu 18.04 but the same thing is happening again. Honestly speaking, I am not an expert on Linux but can do general stuff. I can not understand what causes the problem. I had tried to resolve it by googling but unable to do so.
Graphics on my laptop...

lspci | grep VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3ea0

Laptop Configuration

[image]

I will appreciate any suggestions regarding this issue. Please let me know if you need more info.

Cheers
Razon

Answer (score 0):

If you have nvidia card you should install the nvidia drivers , from your about screen you use the onboard graphics.

Also another idea is to install the new ubuntu lts version 20.04.
New kernel , maybe new drivers there is a chance will fix your problem.

Comment: Hi Aiaf, Thanks for your comment. Actually, I will have to stick with version 18.04 as there are couple of software I am using still hasn't released option for version 20.04. Anyways, Can you please suggest to me how can I perfectly install Nvidea drivers?

Comment: Hope it worked for you , make some search here on askubuntu.Standard way is to use the additional drivers application , or sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall.